# Codeigniter problem with routes!

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to do this route trick:

```
$route['cp/roles/:num'] = "cp/roles/index/:num";
```

but it doesn't work :( 
please help me!!

advanced thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation on [URI Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html):

> `$route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";`
>
> “*A URL with "product" as the first segment, and a number in the second will be remapped to the "catalog" class and the "product_lookup_by_id" method passing in the match as a variable to the function.*”

So, for your particular instance, you would do the following:

```
$route['cp/roles/(:num)'] = "cp/roles/index/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$route['cp/roles/:num'] = "cp/roles";
```

and then instead of passing a variable in your function you use

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

or the number that correspond to the segment.